# WPF use grid as background

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Currently, I can create a grid tag which contain background image and kinect photo (both are image tags).

```
<Grid Name="CompositeImage">
    <Image Source="bg.png" Strech="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Strech" VerticalAlignment="Strech"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding kinectPhoto}" Strech="UniformToFill"  HorizontalAlignment="Strech" VerticalAlignment="Strech"/>
</Grid>
```

But for now, I want to use this grid as background but I can't use it under background tag. Like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <Grid Name="CompositeImage"> ... same as above ... </Grid>
    </Grid.Background>

    <!-- other components -->
</Grid>
```

Is there any solutions to make Grid CompositeImage as background or make it fit the outer grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just let the "background" grid span all rows and columns by setting the `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` properties:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="CompositeImage" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        ...
    </Grid>

    <!-- other components -->
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually did is named two grids the same name `CompositeImage`. What you want to do is this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="bg.png" Strech="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Strech" VerticalAlignment="Strech"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding kinectPhoto}" Strech="UniformToFill"  HorizontalAlignment="Strech" VerticalAlignment="Strech"/>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <!-- other components -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can't use a Grid (or any other UIElement) as value for the Background property (which is of type Brush). You may however use a VisualBrush.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use it as `Background`, then please note that this property takes a Brush.

You can build a `VisualBrush` that will be rendering your grid-with-images, and then use such brush as background.

However, I think all you wanted is to use it as "a background" (not as The Background), and in this case just put it into target Grid, then "maximize it" (colspan=xxxx rowspan=xxx horizontal=stretch vertical=stretch) and move it "backwards" (zindex=somelowvalue or just place it as the first child of the Grid)